# Predefined constant for maximum integer

Tags: r, integer

Doc `?integer` says:

> Note that current implementations of R use 32-bit integers for integer
>   vectors, so the range of representable integers is restricted to about
>   +/-2*10^9

Is there a defined constant that holds this value ?

My use would be for `match`. I can't do `match(x,y,nomatch=Inf)` because `nomatch` will be coerced to `integer` (so `Inf` coerced to `NA`). And I'd rather write `match(x,y,max_int)` (with a documented constant) than `match(x,y,2*10^9)`.

Comment: Yes, `.Machine$integer.max`

Comment: @Florian, please post as answer!

Comment: Sorry, wasn't really sure if it should be an answer or a comment, since it's so short ;) Well, I elaborated a bit should anyone in the future stumble upon the same question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
?.Machine
```

> .Machine is a variable holding information on the numerical
>   characteristics of the machine R is running on, such as the largest
>   double or integer and the machine's precision.

In your case, you could use:

```
.Machine$integer.max
```

which returns:

```
2147483647
```

Comment: I'll highlight this part: `integer.max 
the largest integer which can be represented. Always 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647.`  Though `.Machine` is used for machine specific values in general, this one is constant for all _current_ implementations of R